# How to prove $N$ birds will get infinitely further apart from each other.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose there are $N$ birds sitting randomly in the interval $[0, N]$ on an infinite power line. I numbered these birds going from left to right $1, 2, ..., N$. These birds like to distance themselves from other birds, so they keep shifting their position (one at a time chosen at random). Consider the $i^{th}$ bird is changing its position currently. Let $d_l$ and $d_r$ be the distance from the left and right birds respectively. The $i^{th}$ bird moves a distance $\delta/N$ where
$$\delta = \frac{1}{d_l^2} - \frac{1}{d_r^2}$$

For the birds on the extreme left and extreme right, we have $d_l = \infty$ and $d_r = \infty$ respectively. How do I prove that the distances between the birds goes to infinity?

My approach was to consider this value for every bird
$$\frac{1}{d_l^2} + \frac{1}{d_r^2}$$
and show that this is upper bounded by a relevant decreasing function that goes to zero. This is easy to show for the first and the $N^{th}$ bird, but I'm not sure how to do it for the ones in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this depends how you define "distance between birds". Here are my first thoughts.

Let bird $b_i$ be the bird chosen to move. Its distance from its left neighbor $b_{i-1}$ is $d_l$ and its distance from its right neighbor $b_{i+1}$ is $d_r$. After bird $b_i$ moves, these distances would change to $d_l^*$ and $d_r^*$.

When bird $b_i$ is not on the extreme left or right, it is quite simple to show that $d_l^*+d_r^*=d_l+d_r$.

When bird $b_i$ is on the extreme left or right, it is equally simple to show that $d_l^*>d_l$ or $d_r^*>d_r$, respectively.

Thus, the total distance given by $D:= d_r(b_1)+d_l(b_N)+\sum_{i=2}^{N-1}d_l(b_i)+d_r(b_i)$ never decreases, remaining constant when a bird in $\{b_2,\ldots,b_{N-1}\}$ is chosen and increasing by a term of $d_r(b_1)^{-2}$ or $d_l(b_N)^{-2}$ respectively when either of the birds $b_1$ or $b_N$ are chosen.

Now, the crux is to then prove that $D \to \infty$, as in the worst case, $\sum d_r(b_1), \sum d_l(b_N) <\infty$. I suspect a nice argument involving the Borel-Cantelli Lemma might be helpful.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. The distance between the birds is just the metric distance (for example $b_{i + 1} - b_i$). I'd like to show that the distance $d_r$ and $d_l$ go to infinity.